# How do I copy files which have same name but different suffix in ant copy task?

Tags: ant

I have written the below script which is copying files which were changed after the specified time.  What i also want is to get the same files which has different suffix with these files.

```
<project name="copy latest files test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="C:/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
<property name="src.dir" value="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
<property name="dest.dir" value="tempFolder"/>
<!-- Copy contents of classes folder from source folder -->
<target name="moveFolders" >
    <copy toDir="${dest.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">          
            <scriptselector language="javascript">
            import(java.io.file);
            self.setselected(true);

            </scriptselector>
            <include name="*/**"/>              
            <date datetime="04/20/2016 10:35 AM" when="after"/>

        </fileset>        
    </copy>
</target>
```

I was trying to use , but couldnt figure it out.
The files that are getting copied will have another file in the same folder ending with "-meta.xml" as suffix. What I want is to get those files together as well.

Comment: Could you perhaps supply some examples? Unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: Mark, thank you but I actually resolved this yesterday it self. i will be posting answer soon.